# How to get Synergy working on Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, synergy

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit and Windows 7 64-bit, however, Synergy
only works when a window (application or folder) is open and touching
the edge of the screen where the mouse should "jump".

In other words, if a window is open and maximized, Synergy works
normally.  Without any windows, the mouse does not jump to the other
screen.

My steps:

- (Ubuntu) apt-get install -y quicksynergy
- (Windows) Install Synergy (I've tried both 1.3.8 and 1.4.8 and both
  32 and 64-bit)

On Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit (Synergy Server config):

```
   ~/.quicksynergy/synergy.conf

   section: screens
       myubuntu:
       mywin7:
   end
   section: links
       myubuntu:
               right = mywin7
       mywin7:
               left = myubuntu
   end
```

On Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit:

```
   $ /usr/bin/synergys -f --config .quicksynergy/synergy.conf
   ...
   2012-04-25T14:04:12 NOTE: client "mywin7" has connected
       /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/server/CServer.cpp,287
   (output hangs here)
```

On Windows 7 64-bit:

```
   Synergy 1.3.8 Client on Microsoft Windows 7 x86 (WOW64)
   started client
   connecting to 'myubuntu': ###.###.###.###:24800
   connected to server
   (output hangs here)
```

At this point, things **should** work, but my mouse still can't change screens **unless a window is maximized on my Ubuntu machine.**

Everything is running on port 24800.

No firewall on Ubuntu.  Firewall port 24800 open on Windows 7.

This was previously working on Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 (so only
Ubuntu has been upgraded).

I'm open to using either 32 or 64-bit on either server or client side, but I just want to get it working on Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7!

I'm also using Ubuntu Classic (no effects), and not Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the appropriate [version 1.4.8 of Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/download/) and everything works perfectly.

I'm amazed that you found that trick about an app window on the edge of the screen!